# Broker API, JSON to DataFrame

Tags: python, json, api, pandas

I have tried to get historical data from my broker's API (xTrade Brokers)

I tried first with:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

data=json.loads(history)
dafr = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['col1','col2'])
```

Afterwards I have tried the version beneath but still have not mangaged to get it in proper DataFrame format so I can use it for backtesting.

```
def main():
    # create new api client and connect to the SERVER
    apiClient = APIClient(address=SERVER, port=PORT, encrypt=True)
    # prepare the login command
    loginCmd = loginCommand(USERID, PASSWORD)
    # execute login command and get streaming session ID
    loginResponse = apiClient.execute(loginCmd)
    streamSessionId = loginResponse['streamSessionId']
    print('Logged in as ' + str(USERID))
    # create new stream client with given stream session ID
    streamClient = APIStreamClient(address=SERVER, port=STREAMING_PORT, ssId=streamSessionId)
    print('Streaming opened')
    # prepare get server time command
    getServerTimeCmd = baseCommand('getServerTime', dict())
    # get server time
    getServerTimeResponse = apiClient.execute(getServerTimeCmd)
    print('Server time: ' + str(getServerTimeResponse['returnData']['timeString']))
    # prepare get all symbols command`

    mySymbol = 'EURUSD'
    getHistory = baseCommand("getChartLastRequest", dict(info = dict(symbol = mySymbol, period = 5, start = 1384981096762)))
    history = apiClient.execute(getHistory)
    x = pd.DataFrame(history['returnData']['rateInfos'])
```

I cannot extract the data from that JSON to a DataFrame.

If I print x after the script above. Also if I simply print x it just tells me that name 'x' is not defined.

Comment: Should ``main()`` return ``x``? If ``x`` is not defined, that doesn't sound like a pandas issue.

Comment: x is not defined. I just want to assign the DataFrame to x variable

Answer (score 0):

Passing a string into the DataFrame constructor won't work (it'll just propogate that value).

The best way to do this is to use [`read_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.read_json.html) to read the url/string directly (new in 0.12):

```
df = pd.read_json(history)
```

If you already have it as a string, you can use StringIO to make it file-like:

```
from StringIO import StringIO  # alternatively, from io import StringIO
pd.DataFrame(StringIO(data))
```